# Xlsxwriter count/sum function

Tags: python, excel

Hi i've been using xlsxwriter to scrap some data. 
I've been identifying data via xpaths -> text. As shown in the code below.
I've been trying to use xlsxwriter to perform some average across some cells.
However the output excel file I get "#DIV/0!" in cell G2 but when I double click on each individual cell twice, that cells then gets averaged, I have to do this for all the cells I'm averaging. Any idea how I can over come this issue?

```
for elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="financials_table_ratio"]/tbody/tr[45]/td[2]'):
    PER1=(elem.text)
for elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="financials_table_ratio"]/tbody/tr[45]/td[3]'):
    PER2=(elem.text)
for elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="financials_table_ratio"]/tbody/tr[45]/td[4]'):
    PER3=(elem.text)
for elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="financials_table_ratio"]/tbody/tr[45]/td[5]'):
    PER4=(elem.text)

worksheet.write('B2',PER)
worksheet.write('C2',PER1)
worksheet.write('D2',PER2)
worksheet.write('E2',PER3)
worksheet.write('F2',PER4)

worksheet.write_formula('G2', '=average(C2:F2)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel uses uppercase `AVERAGE()` and not lowercase `average()` so you need to use that with XlsxWriter.

See the [Dealing with formula errors](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html#dealing-with-formula-errors) section of the XlsxWriter docs.

Answer (score 0):

From [Official documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html#formula-result):

> XlsxWriter doesn’t calculate the result of a formula and instead
>   stores the value 0 as the formula result. It then sets a global flag
>   in the XLSX file to say that all formulas and functions should be
>   recalculated when the file is opened.
>
> This is the method recommended in the Excel documentation and in
>   general it works fine with spreadsheet applications. However,
>   applications that don’t have a facility to calculate formulas will
>   only display the 0 results. Examples of such applications are Excel
>   Viewer, PDF Converters, and some mobile device applications.
>
> If required, it is also possible to specify the calculated result of
>   the formula using the optional `value` parameter for `write_formula()`

So, one needs to take some action to perform the calculation, after writing the formula, if one is pressed to see the result (e.g., closing/reopoening, but it may be too "rude").

PS: Given that John McNamara gave a different answer, I guess his would be correct. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32206534/2707864) I would guess my answer is perhaps also correct. I wouldn't know the reason for the difference `0` (in [[1](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html#formula-result)]) vs. `#DIV/0!` (in the OP).

PS2: Other interesting question: [How to make unoconv auto calculate formulae before converting into pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34649793/how-to-make-unoconv-auto-calculate-formulae-before-converting-into-pdf)